# Symfony - Disable required field if the checkbox is checked

Tags: symfony

I have a form on Symfony. 
My form is composed of a text input and a checkbox.

If the user checks the box, the input text is disabled (I use javascript).
However, if the user doesn't check the box, he has to fill in the input text. If he ticks the box, he does not have to do it.

Here is my form :

```
$formBuilder
            ->add('text',      TextType::class,array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank()
            )))
            ->add('box',      CheckboxType::class, array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Box'
            ))

    ;
```

I'm looking for a way to disable text input validation if the box is checked.
How to ignore input text validation if the checkbox is checked?

Do you know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom contraint in this case. You should mark field as non-required and show asterisk (*) for required using javascript. For the backend, you need to create a custom constraint. See symfony documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html